# Update Object with only delta changes from XML

Tags: c#, reflection, xml-serialization, dataset, xml-deserialization

I have 2 datasets loaded with data from two xml files having the same
schema. The files contain data from yesterday and today. I'd like to merge
both datasets in such a way that the resulting dataset should have all the
today's data overriding yestrerday's data.

**CATCH:** the today's
dataset contains only the daily changes (DELTA) and merging should not
remove all
unchanged records from yesterday.

Is it possible that I can acheive this via Reflection?
What's the most efficient way of doing so ?

Any ideas would be helpful..

Comment: I don't see how there could be any solution that require the use of reflection here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk.aspx) method of the DataTable class.

Or you can just use the [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) method of the DataSet class as well.